# Not able to create an XStream Outbound Server in Oracle for the Debezium Kafka Connector

Tags: oracle, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium, oracle-golden-gate

I am following the instructions in the [Official Debezium Documentation for Oracle Kafka connector](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.0/connectors/oracle.html). In the step where I have to create an outbound server, it throws the following exception:

```
ORA-65024: Pluggable database  is not open
```

I have successfully followed all the previous steps in the link. But, being fairly new to Oracle, I failed to come to a conclusion by googling this error. I am using the following command in the SQL Plus to do so which throws the aforementioned error while logged in as c##xstrmadmin user as a sysdba:

```
DECLARE
  tables  DBMS_UTILITY.UNCL_ARRAY;
  schemas DBMS_UTILITY.UNCL_ARRAY;
BEGIN
    tables(1)  := NULL;
    schemas(1) := 'debezium';
  DBMS_XSTREAM_ADM.CREATE_OUTBOUND(
    server_name     =>  'dbzxout',
    table_names     =>  tables,
    schema_names    =>  schemas);
END;
/
```

I also created a new Pluggable Database which is open in this case. I haven't yet applied for the GoldenGate Licence. Might there be a chance that this error is due to the unavailability of the licence? If so, any link which provides a trial version of GoldenGate setup and its instructions would be highly recommended. Trial version because we are currently using it for testing.

Tried the above in Oracle 18c and 12c

Answer (score 0):

alter pluggable database ORCLPDB1 open;